# How right make query trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerUpdateNewsAfterChangeLikes` AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE `News` SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes');
END
```

When i make it query, in phpmyadmin i get error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' UPDATE ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE `News` SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (' at line 1
```

Tell me please why i get this error and how make right it query?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER TriggerUpdateNewsAfterChangeLikes AFTER UPDATE ON Likes
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE News SET 
    CountUpLikes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up');
    UPDATE News SET
    CountDownLikes = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down');
    UPDATE News SET
    CountFavorites = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes');
    END;
```

Unfortunately mysql does not allow for multiple events on the same trigger.

Comment: You can read more about triggers here: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: one trigger is working. very bad, now me need write 3 triggers instead 1(: Thanks for help.